# Question too localized?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185809/warning-mysql-fetch-object-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-res

This question was closed as 'too localized', but it really isn't. Sure, it's poorly written and doesn't provide enough details to be answered, but I don't think that few lines of foreign language embeded into understandable php code would render this question too localized.

Comment: The OP responded to the accepted answer with an additional error message: "_error table '123.iaccount' does not exist_." Since it is unlikely that anyone else will encounter this problem because of a lack of an '123.iaccount' table, it seems too localized to me.

Comment: That simply means that he didn't create that table. Anyone could get this error. Edit: Not specifically this error, but anyone could mess up in the same way.

Comment: It's a question that should arguably be closed and deleted; also "too localized" is as good a reason as any, seeing as the user's problem was solved. What point is there arguing over whether the reason was 100% perfect and correct?

Comment: At the very least the question should be changed to reflect the actual problem. As it is now there's not nearly enough information to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: It has thousands of dupes by users who make the same mistake (sloppy code with no error checking). No point fixing - just delete it, IMO

Answer (score 7):

If you think that "anybody could mess up in the same way" in the future, then is it not extremely likely that someone has messed up in the same way in the past? Instead of trying to attack the choice of "Too Localized" did you search for any duplicate questions indicating that anyone has messed up in the same way before?

[I found 485 with the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22supplied+argument+is+not+a+valid%22+mysql+error). Do we really need to re-open this question and make it 486? Why?

Just because sometimes close reasons overlap, and you may not agree with the chosen close reason, does not mean the question needs to be re-opened or that anything unjust happened. That in and of itself does not magically transform a bad question to a good question, never mind a useful one we want on the site. Besides, the final close reason displayed does not necessarily reflect the reason *all 5* close voters selected - just the majority. So it may be the case that 3 people closed as TL and 2 others closed as NARQ, off-topic, duplicate, what have you.

I am quite happy that TL is being removed - while it does accurately address many closed questions, there will be less swordfights on meta about why a bad question was closed when - really - who cares? The guy got his answer, and it is unlikely to help anyone else, at least not anymore than the 485 duplicates that already exist.

Comment: "there will be less swordfights on meta about why a bad question was closed when - really - who cares?" First, I agree with the latter part of this statement's intent - regardless of how pigeonholed we try to make a polite close message, closed questions usually deserve it. About the swordfights - do you really think that more vague definitions of off topic will clarify things for the people who post questions on meta about their bad questions, or, more likely in my opinion, will it only expand the number of "swordfights"?

Comment: +1 - I agree this doesn't need to be reopened, and you make a good point about the mix of close votes. Heck, google found 21 million results for the phrase `"Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"`.

Comment: @Travis between the *better* definitions of too localized that have been added, and the additional site-specific off-topic reasons, I think the closures will become less vague, not more. YMMV.